# Python code wont print results of program

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Not sure what is happening but i cant get the program to print the results.
The objective is to design a program where i can find out how many months are required to pay off a loan and how much total interest is paid. Also to prevent from overpaying on the loan if the payment is more than the principal. Any help is appreciated:

```
principal = float(input("Principal-------- "))
annual_interest = float(input("Annual Interest-- "))
monthly_payment = float(input("Monthly Payment-- "))
interest_month = (annual_interest/12)/100

months = 0
actual_payment = 0
total_payment = 0
interest_total = 0

interest_calc = interest_month*principal
interest_total = interest_calc+interest_total


if monthly_payment<interest_total:
    print()
    print("Loan Not Approved.")
else:
    interest_calc = 0
    interest_total = 0
    while principal >= 0:
        months= months + 1
        interest_calc = interest_month * principal
        interest_total= interest_calc + interest_total
        actual_payment= monthly_payment - interest_calc
        if actual_payment > principal:
            actual_payment = principal
        total_payment = actual_payment + total_payment
        principal = principal - actual_payment



    print()
    print("Months   : ",months)
    print("Interest :  $%.2f"%(interest_total))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of while principal >= 0, use while principal > 0

The principal amount will always end up being equal to 0, because for the last payment, actual payment = principal, so your code was stuck in the while loop.